# How to import MS Visual C++ 2010 solution or project into Bloodshed Dev C++ 4.9.9.2

Tags: visual-studio, ide, projects-and-solutions, dev-c++

Any suggestion on how to import MSVS 2010 solutions (.sln) or VisualC++ projects (.vcxproj) into Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2?

There is an option to import .dsp project files from VS 6.0, but that about all I could find.

Comment: *Why* on earth would you want to do such a terrible thing?

Comment: Because of M$V$ licensing issues of course.

Comment: Why don't you use VS Express?

Comment: You do have a point. However, I was just wondering if it would be possible to do this import in some easy way. One can always use an alternative IDE, but that is not the point of the question. Thanks anyway for your interest.

Comment: Dev-C++, at least in 4.9, is not an IDE. It's a poor substitute for windows 95 `notepad.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "IDE" doesn't support it in any way, and since development of it stopped a while ago, I imagine there are no plugins that would do it.

You'll have to do it by hand, which probably would also require fiddling with source code, as Dev-C++ 4.9 has terribly old compiler.

I recommend using Visual Studio Express edition, which even in 2012 version will open/convert your projects with ease.